# $\iint d\sigma$, where $\sigma$ is an area which surrounded by $x=a(t-\sin t), y=a(1-\cos t),0\leq t\leq2\pi$

Tags: integration

$\iint d\sigma$, where $\sigma$ is an area which is surrounded by
$x=a(t-\sin t), y=a(1-\cos t),0\leq t\leq2\pi$
and $y=0$

I don't know how to get $y=y(x)$ or without this how to do it?
thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of Green's area formulas, e.g.
$${\rm area}(S)=\int_{\partial S}x\>dy\ .$$
Here $\partial S=\sigma-\gamma$ is the formal sum of the segment $[0,2\pi a]$ on the $x$-axis and the given cycloid $\gamma$ traversed backwards. Since  $dy=0$ along $\sigma$ we obtain
$${\rm area}(S)=-\int_\gamma x\>dy=-\int_0^{2\pi}x(t)\>\dot y(t)\>dt=\ldots\quad.$$